# Looping/Iterating through AWS PHP SDK response

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, simplexml

What I have noticed is that responses from [AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/) are sometimes a single result other times an array of results.

The issue may be because of my lack of knowledge when dealing with CFSimpleXML/SimpleXML Objects.

I have tried several ways of doing this but each one is rather difficult and what I've learned is that after a while of doing things and they all seem difficult, then you are doing it wrong.

## What's Happening

### Example Call With describe_load_balancers

```
<?php

$elb      = new AmazonELB();
$response = $elb->describe_load_balancers();

if ($response->isOK())
{
    foreach($response->body->LoadBalancerDescriptions() AS $loadBalancer)
    {
        print_r($loadBalancer);
    }
}
?>
```

### If it has only one result it prints something like this:

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [member] => CFSimpleXML Object
        (
            [SecurityGroups] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                )

            [LoadBalancerName] => LBName1
            [CreatedTime] => 2012-08-01T12:22:03.910Z
            ...
        )
)
```

### If it has multiple results it prints something like this:

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [member] => Array
        (
            [0] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [SecurityGroups] => CFSimpleXML Object
                        (
                        )

                    [LoadBalancerName] => LBName1
                    [CreatedTime] => 2012-08-01T12:22:03.910Z
                    ...
                )

            [1] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [SecurityGroups] => CFSimpleXML Object
                        (
                        )

                    [LoadBalancerName] => LBName2
                    [CreatedTime] => 2012-08-01T16:17:21.030Z
                    ...
                )
        )
)
```

---

## What I want if there is a single result

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [member] => Array
        (
            [0] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [SecurityGroups] => CFSimpleXML Object
                        (
                        )

                    [LoadBalancerName] => LBName1
                    [CreatedTime] => 2012-08-01T12:22:03.910Z
                    ...
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried to loop through and see if `member` is an array but it still returns it as a CFSimpleXML Object so I was unable to detect the array that `print_r` says is there.

I want to be able to iterate through the list and either make Models of ELBs in my code from the SimpleXML or easily iterate over the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$elb      = new AmazonELB();
$response = $elb->describe_load_balancers();

foreach($response->body->LoadBalancerDescriptions() AS $item)
{
    foreach($item->member() AS $member)
    {
        print_r($member);
    }
}
```

### Prints

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
[SecurityGroups] => CFSimpleXML Object
    (
    )

[LoadBalancerName] => LBName1
[CreatedTime] => 2012-08-01T12:22:03.910Z
```

Edit 9/14/12: Just wanted to do a quick update and share a link I found that helped: [Konrad Kiss' Code & Tech Rant: Listing AWS instances in PHP](http://www.konradkiss.com/2011/06/listing-aws-ec2-instances-in-php_02.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage to_json, to_stdClass and to_array methods of $response->body

```
<?php

require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php';

$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();

$response = $ec2->describe_instances(); 
$instances = $response->body->to_stdClass();

echo count($instances->reservationSet->item).PHP_EOL;

foreach ($instances->reservationSet->item as $reservation) {
    echo $reservation->instancesSet->item->instanceId.PHP_EOL; 
}
```

This already discussed here: [iterating over SimpleXML Objext PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778444/iterating-over-simplexml-objext-php)